# How to set up a filtered data extension that refreshes each time automated email is run

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, refresh

I've set up an automated email to a filtered data extension which utilizes some date logic. This automation runs each day and looks for a specific date.  The data in the data extension this is pointing to never refreshes, it only appends new records.  So, contacts who fall out of the date range of this automated email never drop off.

How would I set this to refresh before each send so I am only grabbing people who fall into the date criteria at the time of the send?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a [Filter Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/filter_activity/) in Interactions.  Once you have one of those, you can add a refresh in your Automation.

Comment: Thanks - I'm having trouble locating where you set the refresh

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Can it be real that you cant say where the output DE goes? only the same? It seems like the DE always are in the same folder as the source DE.

Comment: It's created in the same folder, but you can move it afterward.

Comment: @peachy you have to create filter activity for it and then add the activity to an Automatiion